# One pixel extra with a width of 100%

Tags: css, width, rendering, pixel, percentage

I got a textarea of 680 pixels wide.
This needs to be made fluid so I use percentages.

The percentages make a perfect 100% width but it seems to render 1 pixel more than it should.

http://jsfiddle.net/XXshn/2/

Comment: I don't really see how your text area is fluid, since it's parent has got fixed width eventually the text area is also going to be fixed width. About the one pixel difference is because browser has his owen algo round off the digits in decimal coming after evaluating padding in percentages to pixels.

Comment: The parent is just a "fixed" holder in this example I created. Why would they even round off the digits?

Comment: 94.10029498525074 % of 680 px = 639.88.2006, but browser is taking it to be 639px instead of 640px. Your percentages don't make for perfect 100 since borders are also evaluated as part of width unless you change box-model.

Comment: Border is inside in box model, that was my problem indeed. Thanks!

Comment: I'll do so when I get the necessary rep :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what would be wrong with this:

```
textarea {
border: 1px solid #333333;
background: #ececec;
margin: 0;
outline: 0;
height: 100px;
padding: 20px; /*  */
width: 640px; /* 680px - 2 * 20 */
resize: none; }
```

Comment: I need it to scale when put in a smaller div for example so the percentages are needed.

Comment: ok, so your problem is the border on the textarea, because that is expressed in px instead of %, it will never be correct when you change the size of the outer div.

Comment: move the border from your inner element to the outer element: I have modified your example here: http://jsfiddle.net/b8yxP/